# Regular Expression for ng-pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angularjs-ng-pattern

I want my input text to accept following characters only
**1**,**2**,**3**,**4** and **5+**
And to validate the above character I need a regular expression (ng-pattern).

Is their any perfect website to learn Regular expression?

Comment: Please have a look at http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can learn regular expression here [RegularExpression](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-intermediate-en-NJ7Lr/0/1)

Also you can check for practice purpose [practice](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can experiment RegExp here : https://regex101.com/
When you tip things, it will explain you what it does
That could help you, i don't know if there is tutorial on it through